# Length of array created by using split string

Tags: c#

I know that we can use `string.split()` to put our data into arrays like below:

```
string[] strSplit = Data.Split('|');
```

But can we know how many array items it created? I need that number.

Comment: Do you mean you need the number Before you split the string?

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: If you're after the number of arrays Data contains then you might want to use a foreach for one level or use recursion to drill down through the nested levels. You would still use the .length property to find the size of the .split in strSplit as already mentioned.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It will create a single array of multiple strings. Like T.S. commented, you can get the number  of strings using the length property of the returned array

```
int length = strSplit.length
```

Answer (score 1):

Sometime you need remove the empty entries in spilt result:

```
string[] strSplit = data.Split(new []{"|"}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
```

And get the length like this:

```
int length = strSplit.Length;
```